# Send a variable from AngularJS to Java while closing websocket connection

Tags: java, angularjs, websocket

I want to store the variable X in a file/DB in server side. Client side is written using AngularJS and server side is using JAVA. The Connection is established using WebSocket.

Now whenever the connection is closing(both when I close it manually and when it closes automatically on some error), I have to send the variable X from AngularJs to JAVA. What is the good way to do that?

Connection establishment - AngularJS code

```
angular.module('main')
.factory('socket', function ($websocket,$cookies,$state) {

    // Open a WebSocket connection
    var ws = $websocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/Server/dialog");
    var X = [];

    ws.onMessage(function (event) {
        console.log('message: ', event.data);
        var response;
        response = event.data;

        X.push({
            //some data
        });
    });

    ws.onError(function (event) {
        console.log('connection Error', event);
    });

    ws.onClose(function (event) {
        console.log('connection closed', event);
        X.push({
            //some closing msg
        });
        //From here I have to send the variable X to the server side
    });

    ws.onOpen(function () {
        console.log('connection open');
        ws.send("HELLO");
    });

    return {
        X: X,
        status: function () {
            return ws.readyState;
        },

        send: function (message) {
            if(message != null){
                console.log(message);
                X.push({
                    //some data
                });
                ws.send(message);
            }
        }
    };
})
```

How to send the variable while connection is closing?

Comment: why don't you make an API post request to send data to server inside `onClose` function??

Comment: I haven't done that before. I will try that idea and let you know. Thanks :)